# R: Write table to MySQL error using RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, mariadb, rmysql

I am trying to write a data.frame to a table using RMySQL.

Using the following code:

```
dbWriteTable (mydb, value = dataframe, name = "table", append = TRUE)
```

I get always:

> Error in .local(conn, statement, ...): could not run statement: The
>   used command is not allowed with this MariaDB version

I tried the command without an existing table (with `append = FALSE`). But a table was created without any data written in it.

the data frame looks like this:

```
date forecast  lt st combined
16611  0.0874 0.7  0     0.7
16612  0.0853 0.7  0     0.7
16613  0.0844 0.7  0     0.7
16614  0.0822 0.7  0     0.7
```

The columns in mysql table have the same names and are all double. The table is empty

Any suggestions? Is there another way to do it?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you please show the data in `dataframe`. Also if `append = TRUE`, the data types of the columns in `dataframe` must match the data types in the database table. If you are using `append = FALSE`, make sure that your data.frame contains data.

Comment: the data.frame has the following format:

Date, forecast long short combined
16624  0.01       0.3   0        0

the table in mysql has the same column names and all are formatted as double. The table is empty. Many thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please add the data to your question? Give me something so I can actually reproduce the error on my machine.

Comment: You need to add it to the question; like above, not in the comments. I have no idea how the data.frame is structured.

Comment: Carlos... a well written question with sample data gets an answer. Edit your Q, add your data in a code block (Ctrl-K), that way people would understand it and experiment with it. Master Stackoverflow, then your future is filled with milk and honey.

Comment: many thanks for the support and clarification Abdou and Paulb

Comment: @carlosmaria, it seems like your problem is that you are naming your destination table table. The keyword "table" is reserved in most database systems. So try: `dbWriteTable(mydb, value = dataframe, name = "testTable", append = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)`.

Comment: Many thanks Abdou, unfortunately the same error comes up. It creates the table but it is empty and the same error message appears. If I rename the existing table and try your code with the new name I get also the same error message. In the database the table has columns with the same names as the dataframe, al are type double and "Date" is the primary key.